# how to set value for perticular index in CoreData. iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my app I have used core data and on button press of uitableview cell I delete or pin unpin the value.

So on the click of button, I want to set value of that index.

Here is my code:

in cellforrow at index path method

```
cell.pinButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.pinButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MessageViewController.buttonDeletePressed(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


    cell.btnpinUnpin.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btnpinUnpin.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MessageViewController.buttonPinPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

and these are function

```
func buttonDeletePressed(sender:UIButton) {
    //        let index = sender.tag
    //        print(index)
    //        let feedId = person?.valueForKey("feed_id")?.objectAtIndex(index)
    //        deleteFeed(feedId! as! String)

    let index = sender.tag
 //   print(index)
    moc.deleteObject(people[index] as NSManagedObject)
    people.removeAtIndex(index)
    let _ : NSError! = nil
    do {
        try moc.save()
        self.feedTable.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print("error : \(error)")
    }

}


func buttonPinPressed(sender:UIButton) {
    //        let index = sender.tag
    //        print(index)
    //        let feedId = person?.valueForKey("feed_id")?.objectAtIndex(index)
    //        deleteFeed(feedId! as! String)

    let index = sender.tag
 //   print(index)
    //   moc.deleteObject(people[index] as NSManagedObject)

    if (person?.valueForKey("isPin") as! String == "1")
    {
        person?.setValue("0", forKey: "isPin")
    }
    else
    {
        person?.setValue("1", forKey: "isPin")
    }


    //   people.removeAtIndex(index)
    let _ : NSError! = nil
    do {
        try moc.save()
        self.feedTable.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print("error : \(error)")
    }

}
```

By this I can delete whole object correctly. But when I tape on pin button every time its selecting last value. Reason is that I can not set index for that nsmanagedobject. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `person = people[index]`

But, your real issue is that you're using tags and this forces you to reload the table all the time, because otherwise a lot of the tags are wrong after a delete.

It's also recommended to use an FRC as the data source, then you can animate your updates.

In order to achieve that you'd create a custom cell class so you can pass it something better than a tag value. That might be the managed object itself (not ideal), the object is for the managed object (better), or a different class, like a view model, which knows what to do when the button is pressed (and could provide data for the cell to display too) (best).